# Laravel загрузка картинок из базы данных циклом

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel 6.2 не получается загрузить картинки из базы данных циклом.

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <a href="#">
         {{ $product->photo }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Выводит только ссылки из базы

```
<img class="pic-1" src="images/пример/пример.png">
```

Еще вариант

```
<a href="#">
    <img class="pic-1" src="{{ $product->photo }}">
</a>
```

Ничего не выводит. В коде хелпер, в src , даже не понимает что это php код

Answer (score 0):

Решено

```
{!! $product->photo !!}
```

Blade экранирует теги...